# Game crashes  with NSLog errors (cocos2d iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, crash, assertion

In my game, I made many methods in GameLayer that I need to call in Level1. I'm not sure why, but I when I click start, I get this error in the console, and the game crashes.

```
Assertion failure in -[CCTimer initWithTarget:selector:interval:]
```

followed with

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Signature not found for selector - does it have the following form? -(void) name: (ccTime) dt'
```

I've uploaded GameLayer.h and .m here: http://www.4shared.com/file/O_1utrRj/undefined.html

Note: Level1 (where I call the methods) is in GameLayer.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile on my XCode.

Comment: I only included the 2 files that had the problems, not Helloworld, resources, etc

Comment: I read your source (partly, since you did post a whole XCode project). This is too broad for StackOverflow, and even the code reviews sister site.

Comment: What do you mean by that? It's too complicated of a question?

Comment: You should not ask people to go and read the code for your project. You are supposed to hunt the bug zone down and show it into your question.

Comment: Ok sorry, I usually don't do that but I thought that since I was offering most of my reputation that it was acceptable. I'm a bit busy right now, so I will use breakpoints tomorrow and see where the problem is

Comment: Please narrow down this this question to where the exception is raised. Also posting your code to a premium fileshare site which makes people wait 20 seconds before they can download is not really acceptable. If you have too much code to post then we prefer you use a pastebin type site, but please don't expect our community to read through hundreds of lines of code to try and help you. Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Feel free to flag to re-open once you've improved the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written a call to a method moveBunnyM that doesn't exist. When it's effectively called, your application crashes.

What you *have* written however is a method moveBunnyM:(float) delta

Replace line 173:

```
[ptr moveBunnyM];
```

with

```
[ptr moveBunnyM:(float)dt];
```

since you call this method from a method called moveBunny that happens to take  a dt parameter

This will eliminate one crash, but it shows that you have serious logic issues with your source.

Piece of advice: do not put several @implementation in the same .m file. Create several files, one per class. Level1 should be defined in Level1.h, with an import of Cocos.h, and implemented in Level1.m, with an import of Level1.h.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes a lot more sense. My mistake. I'm still getting the console errors and crash though. Anything I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a look into your project (merely because I want to see what happens with the purple rabbit).

Comment: Haha ok thanks. What is supposed to happen is that it is the hero, and can be controlled with the joystick, and also shoot projectiles with the other joystick. I've tried collision detection but didn't get to test it yet because of this.

EDIT - Is it bad practice about the implementation, or is there something wrong with it? I find it easier and more convenient, but if it's a problem I'll change it. Also, the GameLayer files I just uploaded have been updated and are different from the one I posted before with the entire project.

Thanks for the help so far

Comment: OK, I'll get the new versions and have a look. For the implementation, it's bad practice yes. It works, as you have noticed, but what if you have two categories and three classes in a file, and you do that in several places? Your project will soon be unmanageable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and support, I'll change it

Comment: I've gotten your file, but it opens as a cpgz that gives me a zip that gives me a cpgz etc. It looks like corruption of the archive to me. What did you change in those files, maybe I'll just be faster editing them here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3116/discussion-between-kheldar-and-joethemonkey101)

Comment: I think there was something wrong with the upload. Here's the entire project. I just uploaded it so it's updated. http://www.4shared.com/file/jJUVJ7HT/undefined_2.html
Not sure why the name is undefined. Usually it's the name of the file

Comment: Hi, did you get a chance to look at the updated project?

Comment: Get onto the chat at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3116/discussion-between-kheldar-and-joethemonkey101